# How can I add all my contact list to telegram channel automatically?

Tags: telegram-bot

I have a list of phone numbers in an excel file, and I want to add them to my channel in telegram messenger.

I found a way which convert excel file to CSV and CSV file to VCF file type, by this way add them to my phone's contact list, then manually add all the contacts to my channel.

Is it possible to add whole the contacts automatically?

Comment: Do you want to get blocked for spam? Because that's how you get blocked for spam.